# Python finding words in file based on passed value

Tags: python

I want to create simply method, where programm will find word or words in file, based on passed value from command line.

```
class Option():
    SCRABBLES_SCORES = [(1, "E A O I N R T L S U"), (2, "D G"), (3, "B C M P"),
                (4, "F H V W Y"), (5, "K"), (8, "J X"), (10, "Q Z")]
    global LETTER_SCORES 
    LETTER_SCORES = {letter: score for score, letters in SCRABBLES_SCORES
             for letter in letters.split()}

    def word_from_score(self,score):
        file = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('dictionary.txt', "r")]
```

For example, if I run python main.py -s 7 it will return KOT. I know how to create argparse, but have problem with finding words and adding them to list

[EDIT]
I wrote something like this:

```
def word_from_score(self,score):
    file = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('dictionary.txt', "r")]

    return [word for word in file if sum([LETTER_SCORES[letter] for letter in word ]) == score]
```

Comment: To make sure I understand it right, your problem is that you have a list for valid words read (correctly without trouble) from your file, and you are now looking for a way to check which of those words can be created with a set of letters passed via command-line?

Comment: @Henning Koehler not really. I got file with words. Now from command line, I want to write python main.py -s 7. 7 is a score I want to find in file. For example KOT return value 7. And I want to do opposite. I want to write 7 as argument and get KOT as result or other words I have in file and sum of characters based on LETTER_SCORES is equal to passed argument

Comment: So you are looking for a way to compute the sum of char values of the words parsed so that you can compare it to the target score?

Comment: Exactly. And in file can be a lot of words that sum of letters is equal to my target from command line, so I want all of them store in list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension is your friend here. To compute the score of a word:

```
def scoreOf(word):
    return sum( [ LETTER_SCORES[letter] for letter in word ] )
```

and to filter out all the matching words:

```
def wordsWithScore(allWords, targetScore):
    return [ word for word in allWords if scoreOf(word) == targetScore ]
```

Or if you really want to, you can even combine them into a one-liner:

```
return [ word for word in allWords
         if sum( [ LETTER_SCORES[letter] for letter in word ] ) == targetScore ]
```

Comment: I changed my first post.

Comment: So if that is working now, then please accept the answer. Otherwise you'll need to clarify what it is you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I will do that if everything work fine. But I want these selected words add do list and return only 1, based on random